# Put a condition > equal < value in VB.Net solution

Tags: vb.net

how should i put a condition, display only variants of 1,2, 3, 4 numbers, or 5 numbers.

```
Function SumUpRecursive(numbers As List(Of Integer), target As Integer, part As List(Of Integer), solutions As List(Of List(Of Integer))) As List(Of List(Of Integer))
    Dim s = part.Sum()
    If s = target Then
        ' MsgBox("sum(" & String.Join(",", part.[Select](Function(n) n.ToString()).ToArray()) & ")=" & target)
        solutions.Add(part)
    End If
    If s >= target Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    For i As Integer = 0 To numbers.Count - 1
        Dim remaining = New List(Of Integer)()
        Dim n As Integer = numbers(i)
        For j As Integer = i + 1 To numbers.Count - 1
            remaining.Add(numbers(j))
        Next
        Dim part_rec = New List(Of Integer)(part)
        part_rec.Add(n)
        SumUpRecursive(remaining, target, part_rec, solutions)
    Next
    Return solutions
End Function
```

Button:

```
 Dim numbers As Integer() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
        16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
        35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,
        54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72,
        73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80}
    Dim target As Integer = 15
    Dim nums = SumUpRecursive((numbers.ToList()), target, New List(Of Integer), New List(Of List(Of Integer)))
    If nums Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Failure :(")
    Else
        TxtListScanTxt.Lines = nums.Select(Function(b) String.Join(", ", b)).ToArray()
    End If
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 9
1, 2, 4, 8
1, 2, 5, 7
1, 2, 12
1, 3, 4, 7
1, 3, 5, 6
1, 3, 11
1, 4, 10
1, 5, 9
1, 6, 8
1, 14
2, 3, 4, 6
2, 3, 10
2, 4, 9
2, 5, 8
2, 6, 7
2, 13
3, 4, 8
3, 5, 7
3, 12
4, 5, 6
4, 11
5, 10
6, 9
7, 8
15
```

Let's just say I want to display only the 3 combinations (only 3-digit combinations.)

```
3, 4, 8
3, 5, 7
4, 5, 6
```

and so on...

how do i improve the code to do this? to calculate only the combinations of 3, 4, or 5, not all. because otherwise the program would crash, there are too many combinations. for large amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some overloads to help with this

Code in a Module:

```vb
Public Function SumUpRecursive(numbers As IEnumerable(Of Integer), target As Integer, solutionLength As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of Integer))
    Return SumUpRecursive(numbers, target).Where(Function(item) item.Count() <= solutionLength)
End Function
Public Function SumUpRecursive(numbers As IEnumerable(Of Integer), target As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of Integer))
    Return SumUpRecursive(numbers, target, {}, New List(Of IEnumerable(Of Integer)))
End Function
Private Function SumUpRecursive(numbers As IEnumerable(Of Integer), target As Integer, part As IEnumerable(Of Integer), solutions As List(Of IEnumerable(Of Integer))) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of Integer))
    Dim s = part.Sum()
    If s = target Then solutions.Add(part)
    If s >= target Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    For i As Integer = 0 To numbers.Count - 1
        Dim remaining = New List(Of Integer)()
        Dim n As Integer = numbers(i)
        For j As Integer = i + 1 To numbers.Count - 1
            remaining.Add(numbers(j))
        Next
        Dim part_rec = New List(Of Integer)(part) From {n}
        SumUpRecursive(remaining, target, part_rec, solutions)
    Next
    Return solutions
End Function
```

Code in Form:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim low = 1, high = 80
    Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(low, high - low + 1)
    Dim target = 15
    Dim nums = SumUpRecursive(numbers, target)
    If nums Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Failure :(")
    Else
        TxtListScanTxt.Lines = nums.Select(Function(b) String.Join(", ", b)).ToArray()
    End If
End Sub
```

Also notice that some code was simplified such as your list of integers automated

```vb
Dim low = 1, high = 80
Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(low, high - low + 1)
```

(If you want to exclude some numbers, you can do it like this (sorry I didn't bother seeing if all your numbers from 1 to 80 are in fact there)):

```vb
Enumerable.Range(low, high - low + 1).Except({1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55})
```

So, once you have overloads, there is no reason to call the large recursive function, passing new lists, which is really confusing for anyone else using your code (your professor?). You can hide that one with access modifiers and simply call a simpler overload.

Types have been changed to `IEnumerable` instead of `List` whenever possible.

But the key to limiting solutions to a maximum number is in the first overload,

```vb
SumUpRecursive(numbers, target).Where(Function(item) item.Count() <= solutionLength)
```

Of course, if you want to limit to a single quantity, you can do

```vb
SumUpRecursive(numbers, target).Where(Function(item) item.Count() = solutionLength)
```

and that could be put in a separate overload if you like. A min/max range could also work.

I hope some of this is useful.

Comment: Yes cool. thank you to everyone who contributes to the development with a piece of code. to teach everyone and develop new projects.